# Etymology of orchard

Tags: etymology, latin, old-english, german

Etymology of orchard

As a German I would assume that *orchard* is related to German *Obstgarten* (a garden  with fruit trees), and as *Obstgarten* has a consonant group of four consonants bst+g the bst was somehow reduced and changed.

Etymonline states that the second word element is *geard* meaning *garden/yard*. As to the first element there seems to be some uncertainty. Etymonline says "perhaps reduced from *wortgeard*, from *wort* vegetable, plant root". That seems to be a bit doubtful as apples are no vegetable. Etymonline's affirmation that the first element is influenced by Latin *hortus* (garden) may be, though a word composition like "garden garden" or "enclosed garden" (a tautology) is not very logical.

Anyway, somehow an r was inserted however it may have happened, but I think the most plausible etymology is a relationship with Obstgarten.

I would guess obs- was reduced to long open o and written or- and -t+geard/yard became the sound /tsh/ written ch.

I would like to hear any comments.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19523/discussion-on-question-by-rogermue-etymology-of-orchard). Please see [that chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19523/discussion-on-question-by-rogermue-etymology-of-orchard) before commenting here: your comment may be relevant there.

Answer (score 4):

No, you are almost certainly mistaken about any overt borrowing from German *Obstgarten* to produce English *orchard*.

You are struggling too hard to look for an added *-r-*, when in fact, it was already present in Latin *(h)ort-(us)* right from the get-go.   There were also cognate Gothic words starting with *aurt-*.

However, there is nothing resembling the German word *Obstgarten*.

Regarding *orchard*’s etymology, the OED states the following:

> #### Etymology
>
> orig. OE. *ort-ʒeard*, parallel to Gothic *aurti-gards* garden, the first element of which is considered to be Latin *hortus* (in late and medieval Latin *ortus*, Italian *orto*) garden. Cf. Gothic *aurtja* gardener, and OHG. *orzôn* ( :– **ortôjan*) to cultivate.
>
> Already in 9th c., OE. *ortʒeard* passed into *orcʒeard*, *orceard*, whence ME. *orchard*; also, with recognition of the second element *orch-yard*, *ort-yard*, or, with later conformation to Latin *hortus*, *hort-yard*.

The word has had many, many, many, many, many — did I mention many? — spellings in its history since King Ælfred the Great first wrote about it in 897 ᴀᴅ.

The OED lists 44 (yes: ***forty-four!***) different historical spellings of the word, divvying these many forms up into four main sets, denoting each set with a Greek letter and with numbers indicating the *n*<sup>th</sup> century (and “1” means from **before** 1000):

> ### α.
>
> 1 *ortʒeard*, *ordceard*,
> 4 *ortyerd*,
> 6 *ortyerde*, *ortȝard*, *ortiard*, (*ortesyerde*),
> 6–7 *ortyard*,
> 7 *ort-yard*.
>
> ### β.
>
> 1 *orcʒeard*, *-ʒyrd*,
> 1–2 *orceard*,
> (1 *orcird*, *‑yrd*, *‑erd*),
> 3 *orchærd*, (*horechard*),
> 3–6 *orcharde*,
> 3– *orchard*;
> (4 *orichard*,
>  4–6 *orcherd(e*,
>  5  *Sc.* *orchart*,
>  6 *ortchard*, *north.* *orchert*, *‑erit*).
>
> ### γ.
>
> 4 *orchiard*, *orcheȝerde*, *‑ȝarde*, *‑yerde*,
> 4–6 *orcheyarde*,
> 5 *orche-ȝerd*, *orcheyerd*,
> 6 *orchiarde*, *orchyarde*, *orcheyard*,
> 6–7 *ortchyard*, 
> 7–8 *orchyard*.
>
> ### δ.
>
> 6 *horteyarde*, *hortyeard*,
> 6–7 *hort(e)yard*,
> 7 *hort-yard*: see ***hortyard***.

Not a single one of those 44 historical forms bears any real resemblance to German *Obstgarten*, except insofar as the second element shares a common ancestor in Primitive Germanic with the second element of Modern English *orchard*.  That second element was *gart* in OHG and *geard* in Old English, a word that also gave rise to *yard* in English, and which is closely related to the current Northern English word *garth* from Old Norse *garðr*.

Given this evidence, I believe your notion that *Obst-* contributed to *orchard* is wholly unfounded. All historical records stand against that idea.

Comment: The Gothic word is most likely not just a cognate, but a parallel borrowing, also having _(h)orti-_ from the Latin as its first member, or conceivably having borrowed a Proto-Norse version of the _wurti-_ root very early on. There are very few Nordic loan words in Gothic, though, so the Latin path is quite a bit more likely there.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet For a good time — or perhaps a rather distasteful one — consider also the etymological connection to the now-forbidden French “delicacy” known as the ***(h)ortolan***, the common garden bunting whose taxonomic binomial is *Emberiza hortulana*.

Answer (score 2):

It is more likely from two OE words: *hort* from the Latin *hortus* for garden and *geard* from the Old High German *gart*. Making it a *garden* in the *garden*.

Phonetically it is a small matter for the leading h to be dropped, and then the dental t interacts with the guttural g to move the dental formation to the current ch before spelling was normalized.

Comment: I'd interpret _geard_ as _yard_ and the whole word as _garden yard_, _garden space_, or similar.

Comment: 1) There was no h to lose. The h had already been lost in Vulgar Latin on its way to Old French. 2) The g was not a guttural. /g/ was already palatalised and fricativesed to [j] by the time of Old English—much earlier, in fact. So _hortgeard_ is really just an OE way of spelling what we would probably now spell _ortyard_.

Comment: I agree with jocap that the CURRENT interpretation would be "garden in the yard", but yard is a phonetic adaptation of the OE geard, which ORIGINALLY meant "garden" in essentially the same sense as the Latin hort.

Comment: I agree with Janus Bahs Jacquet that the h was generally not pronounced in VL, which is why it was such a small matter to drop it from the normalized spelling. The detailed explanation of moving from the Germanic guttural to the OE pronunciation also adds value to the discussion.